# TRANSFER a java class macaddress.java output STORED IN A STRING value to a HIDDEN text field MAC in LOGINPAGE.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, netbeans-6.9

Java class program **macaddress**  which holds the *macaddress* address of a local host.... and other is a **loginpage.jsp**... i need to include the java
class **macaddress** output which is stored in a string `macaddress=00-K0-89-9D-JY` in a `hidden text field` which wil fetch BE ABLE TO FETCH the MAC address along with username and password...can anyone explain with a simple 
source code...how to `TRANSFER a java class output STORED IN A STRING value to a HIDDEN text field MAC in LOGINPAGE.jsp`...
thanks for ur time,
regards,
dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("macaddress", "00-K0-89-9D-JY");
```

In your jsp file:

```
<input type='hidden' value='${macaddress}' />
```

Comment: ... hii.... listen i just want the output which is from macaddress.java to be fetched automatically to loginpage.jsp not through servlets